# Android: extract data from external XML file and store them in internal XML file (same file structure)

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I'm building an app which takes some data from a Web XML file (similar to RSS feed) and shows those data in a Webview.
This is done through a DOMParser activity which i feed with different XML URLs.

Now, i would like to take some of these data and store them in the internal storage (a kind of "Favorite" option), to let the user to see them offline.

To see these stored data, i would like to use the same DOMParser, feeding an internal path instead of a web URL (so i don't need to create another activity).

To go in this way, i need to create an empty XML file somewhere (res/XML/file.xml), store the necessary data inside this file (whenever the user choose to do it) and let the user to retrieve the data from this XML (instead of the one on the web URL) when offline thorugh the DOMParser.

Which is the better way to store data to keep what above?
Is SQLite able to store and delete data in a XML file or do i need to use other tools?

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store this files inside res/xml folder, it's not allowed. You can store it in filesystem. Android official tutorial explains [storing file](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)s in great details.

When you store files or read them you have to work with Streams.

**Update in response to first comment**

It depends how big and complex is that part of XML data. If you wish to retrieve that part XML in whole then I would go with filesystem.

SQLite would be a good choice if you like to have SQL structure in respect to your XML part, then you could benefit e.g. creating query to find XML bits you are interested in. I don't see a point to use SQLite and store XML part as a String per row.

If you still don't know which to chose, have a look at example implementations and see which one is more comfortable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't need to store whole files. I need to insert data from XML to a stored XML. In this case, Streams is the correct choice? Because checking on Stackoverflow, i found a similar question where they were speaking about using SQLite database.